# Create sparse band matrix in matlab with variable distance of elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to create a sparse matrix in matlab for calculating the second derivative. Currently I create it in the following way:

```
r_num = 1000;
r_square_num = r_num*r_num;
A = sparse(-30*diag(ones(r_square_num,1),0)+16*diag(ones(r_square_num-r_num,1),r_num)+16*diag(ones(r_square_num-r_num,1),-r_num)-diag(ones(r_square_num-2*r_num,1),-2*r_num)-diag(ones(r_square_num-2*r_num,1),2*r_num));
```

But that way is impossible due to `diag` and `ones` creating dense matrices, which will overflow my memory. If the position of the secondary and ternary diagonals is already known in beforehand, then I can rewrite it in the following way:

```
A = spdiags([-1*ones_vec 16*ones_vec -30*ones_vec 16*ones_vec -1*ones_vec], -2:2, r_square_num, r_square_num);
```

But how can I do that if the distance between the diagonals is depending on `r_num`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd input argument (`d`) can be any vector, e.g. `[-1:1]`, `[-2,0,2]` or `[-5,3]`. Thus, the following should work:

```
A = spdiags([-1*ones_vec 16*ones_vec -30*ones_vec 16*ones_vec -1*ones_vec], (-2:2)*r_num, r_square_num, r_square_num);
```